# How to ensure a broadcast receiver remain running and listening for incoming text messages without being killed by OS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an android app that listens for incoming text messages and then syncs with the backend. The app so far is running ok but after some time the app does not receive any incoming message unless when I open the app again. Have explored various options suggesting implementing JobService or just service but the more research am doing the more am getting confused. For the JobService I can see it only meant to schedule job after some time and the service might be killed once the job completes. I need help on the best way to work it out. Below is my code for the broadcast receiver class;

public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private static MessageListener messageListener;
Handler mHandler;

private static final String TAG = "MessageReceiver";

public MessageReceiver() {

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

   if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
       final Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
       HandlerThread bgHandlerThread=new HandlerThread("MyCoolBackgroundThread");
       bgHandlerThread.start();
       mHandler=new Handler(bgHandlerThread.getLooper());

       Runnable backgroundRunnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               passReceivedMsg(data);
           }
       };
       mHandler.post(backgroundRunnable);

   }

}
```

I have implemented an interface where I pass the received TextMessage Object,

```
    private void passReceivedMsg(final Bundle bundleData) {
    if (bundleData !=null ){
        try {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundleData.get("pdus");
            if (pdusObj != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage =
                            SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: currentMessage: "+currentMessage);

                    messageListener.getReceivedMessage(currentMessage);
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage: message "+currentMessage);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Error occurred "+e);

        }

    }

}

public static void bindListener (MessageListener listener){
        messageListener = listener;
}
```

The MessageListener is as below;

```
public interface MessageListener {
    void getReceivedMessage(SmsMessage message);
}
```

Below is my manifest

```
       <receiver
            android:name=".utils.MessageReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Where and how are you registering `MessageReceiver`?

Comment: I have created a class (MessageReceiver ) that implement the Broadcast receiver. I have a listener interface where am passing the received TextMessage Object.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I was asking. Do you have a `<receiver>` element in the manifest that is pointing to `MessageReceiver`? Or are you calling `registerReceiver()` somewhere to register `MessageReceiver`?

Comment: I have it on the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where you think your `MessageListener` object is coming from.

Please understand that your application process does not run forever. As soon as your app's UI moves to the background, [Android can terminate your process at any time](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle). This gets rid of any `MessageListener` object that may exist.

And so what is happening, most likely, is that you set up this `MessageListener`, and it works for a while, until that original process gets terminated. Future SMS messages will start a fresh process for your app, but you no longer have your `MessageListener`, and so your work does not get done.

Instead, get rid of `MessageListener` and whatever `static` field you are using to hold the reference to it. Have your `BroadcastReceiver` use `WorkManager` to do its background work, where your `Worker` can handle everything itself, without relying upon any activities, etc. of your app necessarily having run in the current process.

Comment: Noted. But I still have some concern with Broadcast receivers, since at some point if the onReceive method of the broadcast receiver does not get called after some time, the app might get killed, is there a way to overcome this. I am asking this since I want when the user installs this app it should start intercepting all incoming messages with a user not required to keep restarting the app.

Comment: @Jack: Your receiver is registered in the manifest. Even if you do not have a process running ("the app might get killed"), you still will receive the broadcasts. Android will fork a fresh process for you, then call `onReceive()` of your `MessageReceiver` in that process. However, at that point, you have no `MessageListener`. This is why you need to get rid of the `MessageListener` and have the `MessageReceiver` not assume that anything is in memory from some previous process of your app.

Comment: Now, this makes sense to me. Much appreciated. This is where I was going wrong.

Comment: A quick one, I have removed the Listener and everything working ok but when I shut down the android system the Broadcast receiver is not active, am not able to receive any text until I start the app.

Comment: @Jack: How exactly are you determining that "the Broadcast receiver is not active"?

Comment: When a new message arrives I will get a Toast message and the text will be stored on the server.

Comment: @Jack: You may not be able to reliably show a `Toast` from a `BroadcastReceiver`. And network I/O needs to be off-loaded to `WorkManager`, `JobIntentService`, or a foreground `Service`. Not only might your app process not exist prior to receiving the broadcast, but your app process can shut back down milliseconds after `onReceive()` returns. `WorkManager` and the other listed options will help deal with that. If you still have problems, ask a new Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing your current code and providing details of what you are (and are not) seeing.

Comment: Cool, I think asking a new question will make lot of impact considering am self-taught and it's my first time to work with these advanced android components.